# Mirroring iPad to Apple TV using local router and using data connection?

Tags: airplay, television

I have a iPad 3 or the new iPad and it's 3G. I plan on using this at trade shows so I can mirror what's on my iPad to the TV using Apple TV. We'll be using a local router instead of wi-fi because it's a fortune to purchase internet at shows. My question is once I access an app that requires 3g connection will I lose my connection to Apple TV?

Comment: Can you clear up the question for us, I'm confused - using a router instead of Wifi?  Don't you mean using a local router *for* wifi (that has no internet route)?

Comment: I suspect the intention is: He will be using 3G for internet access, but a non-internet connected WLAN as the network for the Apple TV and iPad.

Comment: Correct using a local router with no internet. Then using 3G for internet access.

Answer (score 2):

If your cellular network allows you can turn on the “personal hotspot” feature on iPad and connect Apple TV to that network. Then you can AirPlay the content to Apple TV (not mirroring) and at the same time use the cellular 3G network for internet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the iPad can only have one IP-based connection at a time. That is either local Wifi **or** 3G. I am not exactly sure if you will loose the AppleTV connection or you won't be able to access the internet, but I sure you won't be able to have both.

You might want to try to bring another iPhone or iPad and use it's Personal Hotspot Feature. You would then connect the AppleTV and your new iPad to this Personal Hotspot Wifi.

Please note that the 3G is usually very crowded at trade shows, because you are not the only one using it ;-)